# Conditional probability, 3 variables, lots of unknowns

Tags: probability

The question is:

> Given $P(B|A) = 0.3, P(A) = 0.6, P(B) = 0.4, P(C|B) = 0.4$ find:
>
> - $P(A~\text{and}~B)$
> - $P(B~\text{and}~C)$
> - $P(A~\text{or}~B)$

I am happy with working out the first 2 answers, but I am struggling with the third, the answer has been provided (0.82), but I don't understand how to get there.

I have tried using a tree to help me better understand it, but all I have is:

[probability tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOCCu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P\left(A\cup B\right)=P\left(A\right)+P\left(B\right)-P\left(A\cap B\right)=P\left(A\right)+P\left(B\right)-P\left(B\mid A\right)P\left(A\right)$$

Comment: I think you can skip the final expression, as $P(A\cap B)$ is something the OP has already calculated.

Comment: Thanks for this, I am happy to accept this as the answer, I did suspect this was the case (but couldn't find the literature to support it).

Comment: Glad to help. Essential is of course that you *understand* the first equality. You can easily grasp it by means of e.g. a Venn diagram.

Comment: My assumption was that the events were mutually exclusive, which is why I couldn't understand that A or B not being 1 (since .6 + .4 = 1).

Comment: The answer on the first question gives you a positive $P(A\cap B)$. This contradicts "mutually exclusive". I reckon everything is clear now. If not then let me know.